# Quitar puntos decimales a un numero que entra por medio de un input

Tags: php, javascript

como estan, espero que bien, lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario al ingresar un valor numérico, por ejemplo, 10.000, el sistema sepa que se trata  de un valor decimal, pero que al guardar se guardé como un entero, pero con los 0 es decir 10000, por cierto, todo se haría desde js para juego guardarlo con php

Comment: Nos muestras por favor que has hecho?

Comment: Podrías utilizar [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 0):

lo que dices si es posible del punto de vista matemático/aritmético pero estaría mal si lo planteas de esa forma. Si lo que deseas es hacer un conversión de una unidad a otra por ejemplo, 1.002[km] a 10020[Dm] necesitas tener la equivalencia en este ejemplo seria 1 Kilómetro equivale a 10000 Decímetro por lo que se podría calcular los km a Dm o viceversa con una regla de tres o factor de conversión.

```
var factordeconversion = [1, 10000];
var unidadaconvertir = 10.000;
var resultado = 0;
resultado = (factordeconversion[1]*unidadaconvertir)/factordeconversion[0];

console.log(unidadaconvertir); //Muestra el valor antes de convertir.
console.log(resultado); //Muestra el resultado.
```

Comment: Hola amigo, muchas gracias por responder, me parece bastante acertada  tu respuesta, pero para que funciones correctamente, el array de "factor de conversión" debe de contener el valor ingresado sin los puntos decimales, cosa que también me ayudaría con el proceso

Comment: Creo que no entendiste, el factor de conversión es la equivalencia de una unidad a otra. Dejo unos ejemplos para que se entienda mejor.

De radianes a grados.
factordeconversion = [2*3.14, 360];

De metro a kilometro.
factordeconversion = [1000, 1];

De milimetro a pixel.
factordeconversion = [1, 3.779528]